# How much of America does Saudi Arabia own now days?

Tags: united-states, saudi-arabia

I watched Fahrenheit 911 last night, and they claim that at the time Saudi Arabia owned 7% of the United States.  That was a few years ago; how much do they own now?

Comment: What do you qualify as owning "the United States"?  Land?  Debt?  Hamburgers?

Comment: Note that the movie stated that was how much Suadi Arbians owned...not necessarily how much the government owned. It should also be noted that a) how that number was arrived at has never been explained and b) it's completely devoid of context...lots of property in lots of countries are owned by people that aren't citizens of said country. It, in and of itself, isn't really an indicator of anything.

Comment: Voting to close as it's simply too broad. The original claim is specious, at best, and completely void of context making it next to impossible to compare over time.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, remember that the statement is a product of an imagination of a fiction witer whose demonstrated knowledge of economy is... shall we say questionable at best.

As such, pithy bumper sticker quotes vague enough to be interpreted any which way one wants is not something we can address with any precision.

But there are some possible ways to interpret that we can look into.

## TL:DR: Depending on which things you measure, and which publicly available figures you trust, you get between 1% 3.5% (unlikely) or 1.3%

(real numbers for those methodologies are probably a bit lower)

---

## Details;

1. The most obvious one to measure - and the most **politically relevant one in 2016** - is [US Government debt](http://treasurydirect.gov/NP/debt/current).

   *NOTE: this may be most politically relevant, but is also the most economically-ignorant interpretation of "owning" United States. Debt is **not** ownership - equity is. (and US is not collateral to its government's debt, unlike a house)*

   ```
   Current Debt as of 10/20/2016
   Held by the Public            | $14.3T
   Intragovernmental Holdings    | $5.5T
   Total Public Debt Outstanding | $19.8T
   ```

   How much of that debt does KAS hold (presumably, through its sovereign wealth fund)? That's REALLY hard to answer, because only parts of the amount are known.

   **[CNN Money:](http://money.cnn.com/2016/05/16/investing/saudi-arabia-us-debt-ownership-revealed/)**

   > **Saudi Arabia stockpiled $116.8 billion of U.S. Treasuries as of March**, the Treasury Department announced on Monday, ending four decades of keeping the figure secret.
   >
   > That makes Saudi Arabia the 13th largest foreign holder of U.S. debt, though well behind the $1 trillion-plus owned by China and Japan each. The Saudi figure was first reported by Bloomberg News based on a Freedom of Information Act request.

   ## This makes KAS holders of less than 1% of outstanding publicly held debt.

   There are suspicions that they own more, through less official channels:

   > It is possible that Saudi Arabia owns even more U.S. debt than what was revealed on Monday. **That's because Saudi Arabia's central bank listed owning $587 billion of foreign reserves as of March. Typically, central banks park the majority of their foreign reserves in U.S. Treasuries.** In other words, the numbers don't really add up.
   >
   > One possibility: Saudi Arabia could be taking a page out of China's playbook. Many analysts believe China owns U.S. debt through custodial accounts in Belgium, a relatively tiny country that listed owning over $154 billion of U.S. Treasuries as of March.

   ## Assuming a (probably unrealistic) cap of $500B of the above amount being US Treasuries, we end up at 3.5%. Most likely, this amount isn't Treasuries only but other investments as well. There's no information available to tell what the number is, between 1% and 3.5%.

   ---
2. A second likely figure to measure is how much is KAS invested in overall US capital markets.

   > There is no comprehensive public accounting of the Saudi government’s investments in the United States, although American officials say $750 billion is a plausible figure. ([*NY Times, though i'd prefer a more reliable source*](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/20/business/international/saudi-threat-to-sell-us-assetscould-hurt-but-mostly-the-saudis.html?_r=0))

   Total US capital market size is $58.4T of bonds+equities ([source](http://qvmgroup.com/invest/2012/04/02/world-capital-markets-size-of-global-stock-and-bond-markets/))

   > Separate data about the US from SIFMA, puts the US bond market at just under **$37 Trillion** (including municipal bonds) as of the end of 2011 (a year later than the McKinsey data), and Bloomberg puts US stocks now (April 2012) at about **$21.4 Trillion**.

   ## This gives us a cap of 1.28%.

   However, the amount may be slightly lower since the above figures are just bonds and stocks and exclude alternatives, which would make whole financial market bigger than the #s above imply (as per WIki, "Liquid alternatives became popular in the late 2000s, growing from $124 billion in assets under management 2010 to $310 billion in 2014").

Comment: Good info but likely not complete (not that I think one could write an answer that is complete given how vague the original claim was). The comment in the movie refers to Suadi citizens and it's certainly plausible that they--being extremely wealthy, own plenty of expensive property in many parts of the world. Whether that would add up to 7% or not--or even if it did it'd has any real bearing on anything--is certainly debatable.